# How to decode string using NSSecureCoding in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, nssecurecoding

I am currently trying the iOS 10 Beta and decided to convert my Swift code to Swift 3. Until now, I was able to securely decode a String using

```
coder.decodeObjectOfClass(NSString.self, forKey: CoderKeys.code) as! String
```

After the conversion to Swift 3, Xcode is giving me the following error:

```
'decodeObjectOfClass(_:forKey:)' is unavailable in Swift: use generic 'decodeObjectClass(_:forKey:)'
```

As I mentioned, I'm using NSSecureCoding, so unfortunately `decodeObject(forKey: String)` won't do. Is this a beta bug? What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems `decodeObjectOfClass:forKey:` is imported as generic `decodeObject(of:forKey:)` in Swift 3.

Try this:

```
coder.decodeObject(of: NSString.self, forKey: CoderKeys.code) as String?
```